# Do we have ObjectForScripting property for WebBrowser Control, for Smart Device application?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, smart-device

I am aware of the `ObjectForScripting` property provided for the `WebBrowser` control, which is provided for WinForms application. I am using the `WebBrowser` control in a smart device application. I am not able to find this property.

IS it document somewhere that `ObjectForScripting` is not available for Windows CE?

Also, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation here:

- [MSDN: WebBrowser Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d61470az%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Next to each property you'll see a small PDA icon indicating if the method or property is supported by the .NET Compact Framework (.NET CF):

[image]

So, no. `ObjectForScripting` is not available for Windows CE.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to overcome the absence of such a valuable property. Or there is any place where I can find more about it. (Googling right now)

Comment: Not sure why this property isn't supported in .NET CF. An alternative to use Microsoft's WebBrowser class could be GeckoFX a .NET wrapper based on the same source code as Firefox (http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/).

Comment: Is it like using the open source available for GeckoFX, and writting Webbrowser control for .NET CF?

Comment: Yeah, that's somehow what I had on mind but I can't tell you if that would be the best approach.